# Why MathJax does not render the LaTeX logo with the "\LaTeX" macro?

Tags: mathjax

I'm using MathJax in a hand-written web page (which is unfortunately not online yet, so I cannot point you to the whole source code).

I embed MathJax in the page as follows, which is simply copy/pasted from the official documentation:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "HTML-CSS": {
      webFont: "TeX"
    }
  });
</script>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML.js">
</script>
```

After that, MathJax seems to work well on every formula I tried, but I cannot get it to render the `\TeX` and `\LaTeX` commands to obtain the TeX and LaTeX logos. Everything on the web makes it look like these two commands are supported by MathJax, and I remember of having used them with MathJax in a wordpress blog years ago, so I think there must be some extension or option missing.

So why are those commands not working and what can I do to fix them? Or are they not supported?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 7):

MathJax only processes the *math* on the page, not other text-mode macros.  So if you want MathJax to process the `\TeX` or `\LaTeX` macros, try using

```
$\rm\TeX$ or $\rm\LaTeX$
```

in your page instead.

EDIT: 
Here is an example.  Run the code snippet to see it work.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>

\(\rm\TeX\) and \(\rm\LaTeX\)
```

Comment: This does not work. Anyway, while it is true that \TeX and \LaTeX are text mode macros in TeX and MathJax only implements math mode, they are explicitly listed as supported, for example here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands

Comment: Sorry, forgot that dollar sign delimiters are disabled by default.  Use `\(\rm\TeX\)` and `\(\rm\LaTeX\)`.  The documentation is correct, they are supported -- in math mode.

Comment: The dollar sign is not the problem, I've actually enabled it. Those commands do not work anyway, and the \rm command seems to not be recognized as well. Yes, the documentation says they're supported but they don't work in my setup, that's the whole question.

Comment: I have inserted a code snippet to my answer that you can run (here in this page) to see that it *does* work.  As for the dollar signs, your configuration above doesn't show them being enabled, so you must be using a configuration other than the one you gave here.  It is hard to diagnose your issue when you give incorrect or incomplete details.  If you can point to a live example, or include a snippet like the one I did above, perhaps we can resolve your issue.  But simply repeating "it doesn't work" with no additional details is not likely to lead to anything helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment seemed too harsh. I was only trying to say that the dollars were not the problem of your answer, because neither using dollars or parens made any difference. Actually there is no problem with your answer, because your code snippet obviously works, and the MathJax docs say those command should work, and I remember having used those commands tens of times. The problem I'm facing is very weird, because I cannot reproduce the problem outside of my actual web page which is still offline so I can't show to you. I'm afraid I will have to wait for it to be public and ask again.

Comment: If you are loading content dynamically, there may be a timing issue where MathJax has already run before the content is there.  Are you queuing a typeset operation of loading any new content?

Comment: In the meantime I've found what the issue was. One of the things I do server-side is to automatically hyphenate words of the page, to be able to have good looking justified paragraphs. I didn't realize that the hyphenator didn't care about MathJax so it was hyphenating latex commands... So the question really didn't make sense, should I close it or remove it? Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what was happening.  I don't know what the policy is for deleting questions like this.  Up to you, I would guess.

Comment: I think this answer is very useful as it stands. It works great with \rm, but not with \text or \textrm (or am I doing something wrong?), so this did save me time :)